# Why is 'fetch' replacing current window?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which opens an empty browser window, then i call 'fetch' and get a log file. I then try to populate the document object with the contents of this file :

```
  var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=1200,height=800");

  fetch('/mylogfile.log').then(res => res.text()).then(body => {
    myWindow.document.write('<pre>' + body +'</pre>')
  })
```

It seems fairly easy and straight forward, however this code ***replaces*** my initial window rather than putting it in the new window.

Confusingly, the new window shows an error message, while the original window has its complete contents replaced with the log file. It looks like this :

[image]

I am completely stumped.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce but I cannot. I've created an `index.html` with an `mylogfile.log` and just a simple script tag containing your code running on a Python SimpleHTTPServer. Code works as intended.